# MNIST for ML Beginners tutorial mistake

Tags: tensorflow

In the [MNIST for LM Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) tutorial I believe there is a mistake. I think this part is not accurate:

> Using small batches of random data is called stochastic training -- in this case, stochastic gradient descent.

Stochastic gradient descent is for updating the parameters for each training example (http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#gradientdescentvariants), and in the tutorial batches of size of 100 are used, which I believe would be mini-batch gradient descent instead.

I could be wrong but shouldn't this be changed?

Comment: In neural network training, SGD usually refers to optimization with mini-batches

Answer (score 0):

It is true that stochastic gradient descent (SGD) is referred to as gradient descent with a single data sample on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) and in the Sebastian Ruder's survey. However, it has become quite popular among machine learners to also use the term for mini-batch gradient descent.

When using stochastic gradient descent, you assume that the gradient can be reasonably approximated by the gradient using a single data sample, which may be quite a heavy assumption, depending on the fluctuations in the data. If you use mini-batch gradient descent with a small batch size (100 may be a small batch size for some problems), you are still depending on the individual batch, although this dependence is usually smaller than for a single sample (since you have at least a bit of averaging here).

Thus, the gradient itself (or the update rule, if you prefer this point of view) is a stochastical variable, since it fluctuates around the average value of the complete data set. Therefore, many people use mini-batch gradient descent and stochastic gradient descent as synonyms.